# Assembly function is confusing

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, masm32

This is an assembly function. From what I understand this is a function calculating the checksum of the 32-bit value in `eax` by creating a loop.

My confusion arises as `lodsb` writes the entire 32-bit value. From my understanding, the loop tries to load a byte after reading a 32-bit value, loading zero into `eax` prior to the `test` instruction used for terminating purposes. Please inform me if I'm wrong.

```
Checksum_Calc:
    lodsb
    test        eax, eax        ;avoids null byte in cmp eax, 0
    jz          CheckFunction
    add         edx, eax
    xor         edx, eax
    inc         edx
    jmp         Checksum_Calc
```

Comment: `Loopsb` ?  Was that supposed to be `Loadsb` instead ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can insert a `Movzx Eax, Al` instruction just after the `Lodsb` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Lodsb is putting the number into the `AL` register (the lower 8 bits only)

This line...

```
   Test Eax, Eax        ;Avoid the null byte in Cmp Eax,0
```

...is looking at all 32 bits

Comment: Looking at all bits may be fine (e.g. if previous code ensures that the upper 24 bits of EAX are clear) as nothing else in the code shown changes the upper 24 bits.

Comment: User3187056 included this phrase in his description of the circumstances, `"...I think when loopsb read all 32 bit value..."`

Comment: I'm afraid Brendan is correct. `test eax, eax`, `test al, al`, it doesn't matter. All the function needs to check is if zero is stored in `al`. And that is exactly what the code does. The original poster is simply asking for the affirmation of his understanding of the presented function.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Wikipedia: x86 instruction listings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings) and [Wikipedia: Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) translation of your code fragment into C pseudocode would look like this

```c
eax = 0;
/* some invisible code */
while(true)
{
  al = mem[esi];   /* this modifies only lower 8bits overlayed over the 32bit eax "structure" */
  /* eax = (eax & 0xFFFFFF00) | al; */
  esi = esi + 1;
  if (eax == 0)
  {
    goto CheckFunction;
  }
  edx = edx + eax;
  edx = edx ^ eax;
  edx = edx + 1;
}
```

In general traslating code into another simpler language or even into a graphical language (like the one invented by authors of "Rapid Quality Systems's Code Rocket Designer", see an [example](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Content/Screenshots/New/FlowchartEditor.png)) is the way to go when studying some legacy source code